# Can the has-a relation in OOP become ambiguous or difficult to know?

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, class-design, relationships

Assume I have the following code.

`class D { static Integer i1 = 42; }`

Is it true that D has an Integer? Or is it only for instance variable that we can have a has-a relation?

I also wonder about very similar, if a primitive variable also can make a has-a relation or is it strictly for classes? e.g.

`class D { int i1 = 42; }`

It seems that D has an `int` but it is a primitive and I'm not sure that primitives are legal for a has-a relationship.

To construct an example that might be awkward, I assume that it is not a has-a relation that the `String s1 = "s1";` has a char because it is not that kind of relation even though `s` and `1` are variables types of `char` in this case.

Similarly, I assume it's false that a class or an object "has" something that it only has conceptually or as internal implementation rather than the plain way of how we understand a has-a relation.

AFAIK, Java has no `class Digit`, it has no `class Mantissa`, it has no `class Coefficient` and no `class Fraction` when I browse the javadocs for Java 8, while Java has many classes for many different purposes. I suppose the reason for omitting certain classes that are fairly common concepts could be that the object would not be useful or that the class hierarchy would become unnecessary complex.

Did I understand the usage and definition of the has-a relation? Did I misunderstand something? Are there corner cases that I didn't think of?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the class with objects of that class. In your first example, the class D has an Integer. In your second example, objects of type D have an int. The confusion may be because there is an implicit reference to the class D in objects of type D, which allows you to examine static members

Comment: Has-a and is-a are OOP design guides. Use them as leads and/or checks when writing classes. Application outside an OOP design context may feel weird because it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, when you are introduced to the terms of `is-a` and `has-a`, you mostly learn them as opposed to one antoher `is-a` ≠ `has-a` ( I borrowed the notation from linguists ).

Both terms are used like the everyday-language equivalents:

e.g. »a `dog` **is** an `animal`«

which could be translated to `Java`-lingo:

»The class `dog` **extends** the class `animal`«

The point is here, that you have two classes which have a relationship in some way - of one *extending* the other via `is-a`-relationship.

If you know and understand this one, the other one will be as easy.

Talking about the `has-a`-relationship is a relationship between two classes of being *used* and being *accessible* in a very private way:

»`dogs` have `eyes`« is the way of expressing, that `eyes` are a part of `dogs` and are (in this case) only accessible by this ("instance" of a) dog.

In `Java`-lingo that means:

»The class `dog` has (private) members, of which one of them are `eyes`«. (Nobody would say `dogs` **are** `eyes` to make the contrast clear).

If you look for the signalword `extends`, you have a strong indication, whether you are looking at a `is-a` or a `has-a` relationship.

This is *not* difficult to know and also *not* ambigous.

---

What about your examples?

1) `i1` would be a *special kind* of relationship. In principle, it is a `has-a` relationship. But, what makes it special is, that `i1` is *shared* between `instances`. It would be right to claim, that every instance of `D` has access to the same shared `i1`.

*opposed to*

2) Every instance of `D` has it's own `i1`.

(1) is the communist version of `i1` (*vis comica*).

Comment: I think you should use the word class instead of object. The word object has a tendency to muddle the waters (though it shouldn't). Nice answer.